# Getting started with Atmel AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, microchip

i would love to start learning AVR programing for Atmel's chips. Currently i'm using only Arduinos with their standard API and im really happy with that, however i would like to  learn more and go even deeper. I believe it would be usefull to have a basic knowledge of how things work.

I found some videos on YouTube and i'm really confused. I know that you basicaly need to purchase an AVR programmer for the chip but after searching on ebay i saw that there are too many to chose from. The first chips i would like to start with are the ATtiny85, the ATmega 328 (i have few of them for my Arduino projects) and atleast 1 32bits chip so i get a very basic understanging of the 32bits architecture.

Also since you guys are more experienced than me should i start with AVR or PIC?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: An Arduino can be used to program other AVR IC's using ISP. 
Arduino harder can be repurposed to run other code than the standard Arduino O/S and compiler. 
Within the confines of the OS and language, about the only thing that you cannot do with a standard Arduino is create assembly language instructions. Apart from that you can access all registers and ports and configure all peripherals. You can use interrupts and watchdog timer and more.

Comment: AVR32 is slightly different from AVR and requires a slightly more expensive programmer.

Comment: What is your question? Is it "should I choose AVR or PIC?" Or is it something else that you could figure out from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/22555/49251 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next logical step in your learning is not to jump straight into low level programming of raw chips, but to do low level programming of the Arduino.

Just because the Arduino provides a high level API it doesn't mean that you have to use it.

You can program an Arduino as if it were a plain Atmel chip - access the registers, etc - and program it through the Arduino bootloader for simplicity.

And all this can be done direct in the Arduino IDE.  Just don't use any Arduino API calls and do it all manually yourself.

Once you're happy with that aspect of it you can then move on to playing with hardware programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Please mind that your 'Question' is pretty open.
The only real question I spotted in it was: "Should I start with AVR or PIC".
I think that, with the knowledge of Arduino, it's better to go with AVR.
But then again, this can vary on opinion.

You might want to check some tutorials on how to do the (important) basics.
Maybe you're already familiar with: "Analog Digital Converter", "Timers", "Pulse Width Modulation", "Hardware debounce", U(S)ART, I2C, SPI.
Try to find an interesting project, which will keep you motivated.

The AVR is a bit more bare-metal coding. As you will have to set registers and ports directly. You might want to check some tutorials on it.

And as always, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about developing for AVR, pony up and get an [Atmel ICE](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42330-Atmel-ICE_UserGuide.pdf). As your skills advance beyond blinking an LED, the ability to stop the processor and look at variables and registers is invaluable. It will grow with you, being compatible with AVR32 and SAM. Do not cheap out and buy some Wun Hung Lo eBay programmer or ICE. The problems it will give you are not worth it.